# Switching Static Excel Export Script for All Sheets to Just One Sheet

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an existing app script that takes the many sheets/tabs in my google sheet (which includes a lot of formulas) and then exports the static data without formulas to a secondary sheet ('12345foobarstaticdatasheet'). After this, it saves that as an .xlsx excel file output in a folder ('12345foobarfolder').
I'd like to simply change this script from getting all the sheets to only exporting one by name ('My Foo Bar Sheet'). When I try this I'm getting errors with the for loop (`TypeError: st1.getName is not a function`).
Here's the script to run the process for the whole file including all sheets:

```
function SaveMySheet() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('12345foobarfolder');
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = source.getSheets();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('12345foobarstaticdatasheet');
  for(i in sheets)
  {
    var st1 = sheets[i];
    var st1Name = st1.getName();
    var st1data = st1.getDataRange().getValues();
    var st2 = target.getSheetByName(st1Name);
    if(st2 != null)
    {
      var rng = st2.getDataRange()
      if(rng != null && rng != undefined)
        rng.clearContent();
      st2.getRange(1,1,st1data.length,st1data[0].length).setValues(st1data);
    }
  }
  var blob = getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel('12345foobarstaticdatasheet',"My Report Filename "+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a'))
  folder.createFile(blob);
}

function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(ssID,name){
  try {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ssID + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

    var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

    blob.setName(name + ".xlsx");

   return blob;

  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do. Remove the loop and get the specific sheet with `source.getSheetByName("The name that is in the variable")`

```
function SaveMySheet() {
  var st1Name = 'TheName';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('12345foobarfolder');
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('12345foobarstaticdatasheet');
  var st1 = source.getSheetByName(st1Name)
  var st1data = st1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var st2 = target.getSheetByName(st1Name);
  if (st2 != null) {
    var rng = st2.getDataRange()
    if (rng != null && rng != undefined)
      rng.clearContent();
    st2.getRange(1, 1, st1data.length, st1data[0].length).setValues(st1data);
  }
  var blob = getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel('12345foobarstaticdatasheet', "My Report Filename " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a'))
  folder.createFile(blob);
}

function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(ssID, name) {
  try {
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ssID + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
    var params = {
      method: "get",
      headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
    blob.setName(name + ".xlsx");
    return blob;

  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked! In testing, there is an issue where it seems to still be exporting the previous version of the sheet instead of waiting until the updates go into the output static file ('12345foobarstaticdatasheet') BEFORE exporting it to excel.
I tried introducing  Utilities.sleep(10000); before var blob but I'm still having that issue.
Any ideas?

Comment: posted ^ that as a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708241/ensure-function-to-update-spreadsheet-completes-before-exporting-to-xlsx

Comment: @KevinMalone use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`